# Plotting 6D in python. Plot the rotational angles(Roll, pitch and yaw)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently trying to plot 6D in python using matplotlib. The only problem is I do not know how to plot 6D. I am able to plot in 3D, but I am working with quadcopters and it would be best if I can plot also the roll, pitch and yaw. I am able to receive its roll, pitch and yaw from the camera. The only problem I have now is to graph the received rotational angles(roll, pitch and yaw).

Comment: How is this related to programming? What exactly is the question here?

Answer (score -1):

A good way to visualize more than three dimensions is to use 
[parallel coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates)

You can plot it with [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#visualization-parallel-coordinates). So far is no build-in 
function that ships with matplotlib, but you can find some examples on the internet.